# jquery aviaslider problem

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery avaislider for image slideshow. I am having a problem with it. it is normally working fine. but when i use a parameter in the url, then it is not working. like - 
it is working in "index.php" page
but when i go to another page like - "gallery.php?gid=2008", it is not working. if i only use "gallery.php", it works. i dont know what is the problem. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the same issue I had:

There is this "demopage_switchslider" function in the custom.js which is only needed for the demo page of the author (Line 4 & 88-98).

This function also works with parameter URL and so there is a conflict with your URL ...

Just delete these pieces of code, that´s all!

Cheers!